# jQuery auto complete on select event not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-autocomplete

I am using jQuery auto complete in my web site. I want go to the search result page when user click on the drop down option.. For that I used the "Select" event , but it doesn't fire during select event.

Any ideas ? here is the code

```
 $(function(){
var availableTags = [
            "ActionScript",
            "AppleScript",
            "Asp",
            "BASIC",
            "C",
            "C++",
            "Clojure",
            "COBOL",
            "ColdFusion",
            "Erlang",
            "Fortran",
            "Groovy",
            "Haskell",
            "Java",
            "JavaScript",
            "Lisp",
            "Perl",
            "PHP",
            "Python",
            "Ruby",
            "Scala",
            "Scheme"
        ];



         $('#autocomplete').autocomplete({
            source: availableTags,
                select: function(event,ui){
                    alert("Selected ");
                }
         });
```

Comment: What about checking out the documentation? :\ http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your missing the closing brackets for your `$(function() {` - you need to add `});` at the end ..

```
$(function() {
    var availableTags = [
        "ActionScript",
        "AppleScript",
        "Asp",
        "BASIC",
        "C",
        "C++",
        "Clojure",
        "COBOL",
        "ColdFusion",
        "Erlang",
        "Fortran",
        "Groovy",
        "Haskell",
        "Java",
        "JavaScript",
        "Lisp",
        "Perl",
        "PHP",
        "Python",
        "Ruby",
        "Scala",
        "Scheme"
        ];
    $('#autocomplete').autocomplete({
        source: availableTags,
        select: function(event, ui) {
            alert("Selected ");
        }
    });
});​  // added this
```

[Then it works fine](http://jsfiddle.net/pRPM4/)

Also ensure you have added the correct JS libraries and CSS

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.22/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
```